# Excel VBA: Extremely large file size when using a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have an excel spreadsheet with just over 60 sheets, I used some Vba code as follows which protects each sheet apart from certain columns, This has no effect on file size

```
Private Sub ProtectWorksheets_Click()
'Protects the totals and summary sheets and sets password

Worksheets("Project Totals").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Project Totals").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Project Totals").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("Initial Discipline Totals").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Initial Discipline Totals").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Initial Discipline Totals").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("Discipline Totals").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Discipline Totals").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Discipline Totals").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("Initial Summary Chart").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Initial Summary Chart").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Initial Summary Chart").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("Summary Chart").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Summary Chart").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Summary Chart").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("Summary Table").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("Summary Table").Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
Worksheets("Summary Table").Protect Password:="BIM"


'Protects remaining worksheets while unlocking the comments and discpiline fields

Worksheets("1").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("1").Range("D5:D10000").Locked = False
Worksheets("1").Range("I5:I10000").Locked = False
Worksheets("1").Protect Password:="BIM"

Worksheets("2").Unprotect Password:="BIM"
Worksheets("2").Range("D5:D10000").Locked = False
Worksheets("2").Range("I5:I10000").Locked = False
Worksheets("2").Protect Password:="BIM"


**This is repeated for the next 60 sheeets


End Sub
```

When running the above i end up with a perfectly acceptable file size of around 8mb.

However if the above code is replaced with the following I end up with a file in excess of 45mb.

```
Private Sub ProtectWorksheets_Click()


Dim ws As Worksheet




'Protects remaining worksheets while unlocking the comments and discpiline fields


For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Unprotect Password:="BIM"
ws.Range("A1:Z10000").Locked = True
ws.Protect Password:="BIM"
Next



For Each ws In Sheets
If ws.Name <> "Front Page" And ws.Name <> "Admin" And ws.Name <> "Project 
Totals" And ws.Name <> "Initial Discipline Totals" And ws.Name <> 
"Discipline Totals" And ws.Name <> "Initial Summary Chart" And ws.Name <> 
"Summary Chart" And ws.Name <> "Summary Chart Table" Then
ws.Unprotect Password:="BIM"
ws.Range("D5:D10000").Locked = False
ws.Range("I5:I10000").Locked = False
ws.Protect Password:="BIM"
End If
Next


MsgBox ("All Sheets protected successfully")


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to why i end up with such a large file size when using what seems like better code than the first.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated (and simplified) your code below, and tried two things:

1. Limited the locked cells only to those in the `UsedRange` using `Intersect`
2. Saving as .xlsb (2MB) rather than .xlsm (18MB)

---

```
Private Sub ProtectWorksheets_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Unprotect Password:="BIM"
        Intersect(ws.Range("A:Z"), ws.UsedRange).Locked = True
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Front Page", "Admin", "Project Totals", "Initial Discipline Totals", "Discipline Totals", "Initial Summary Chart", "Summary Chart", "Summary Chart Table"
                ws.Protect Password:="BIM"
            Case Else
                Intersect(ws.Range("D5:D10000"), ws.UsedRange).Locked = False
                Intersect(ws.Range("I5:I10000"), ws.UsedRange).Locked = False
                ws.Protect Password:="BIM"
        End Select
    Next ws

    MsgBox ("All Sheets protected successfully")
End Sub
```

---

I also used the following subs for testing purposes:

```
Public Sub MakeSheets()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 59
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub InsertData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1:I10000").Value = 1
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: My test on 50 empty sheets produced ~35MB file (excel 2013). Same code with full column references - file size: ~60KB.

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I just updated my answer, does that still apply?

Comment: Current version crashes on empty sheets as the intersection is empty:)

Comment: Yep, I just ran it with dummy data in A1:I10000 on every sheet (60 sheets) and got a filesize of 18mb. Not sure if that's good or not ha!

Comment: Woah, saved it as xlsb and massively reduced the filesize!

Comment: Why use `Intersect(ws.Range("D5:D10000"), ws.UsedRange)` instead of `Range("D1:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` ?

Comment: Another approach for reducing file size is to unzip the xlsb, and compress the files again into a zip file with a higher compression preset. After it's compressed, change the file extension back to xlsb. Admittedly it's a hack, but a fun one. I think only Deflate and Deflate64 methods work, although I haven't tested extensively.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, I'm only really trying to make sure OP doesn't extend their usedrange on any one sheet, so that they don't *increase* filesize. It doesn't really make much difference which method you use. I prefer intersect where it's suitable because the xlUp method usually (for me) requires a `With` wrapped around it to make sure the Range and Rows are qualified properly :)